# MapFragment Crashes after app is killed on background

Tags: java, android, mapfragment

Implement googlemap on my project like this

from xml

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

from java

```
public class Search extends Fragment implementsOnMapReadyCallback {
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...
loadMap();
...
}

GoogleMap map;
MapFragment mapFragment;

    public void loadMap() {
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }

@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commit();
    }
```

This works fine even when i change from one fragment to another.
However, after some time, like when the app has been in the background for a long time, when i try opening the app again, it just crashes the app and i get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ticketing.app/com.ticketing.app.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.ticketing.app.Search.onCreateView(Search.java:55)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:694)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f0a0065, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4740)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.ticketing.app.Search.onCreateView(Search.java:55)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:694)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package name is here" >


    <!-- To enable the app display map, you need these permission below. without any of these permission, the app will crash.
       -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Launcher"
            android:label="Appname" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Create_Account"
            android:label="" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Sign_In"
            android:label="" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="Search" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Select_Bus"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_select__bus"
            android:parentActivityName=".Main" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.ticketing.app.Main" />
        </activity>

        <!-- the metadata helps store value that will probably be different across apps but should be accessible in the same way
        the ones below, help store the API key and a google play service integer. Note that these information have to be provided
        when using google play service and the map API.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="api key for map is here"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can i fix this please.

Comment: Please post your mainfest file.

Comment: I just did. The question has been updated

Comment: Look at this tutorial in manifest file I think you missed adding some permission here :http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0):

I think this error can be ignored and app should load just fine.
Try this:

```
View rootView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
        // properly.
        if (rootView != null)
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(rootView);
        }

        try
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.yourMapFragment, container, false );
        }
        catch( InflateException ex )
        {
        }

        ...
        return rootView;
    }
```